# Exporting template function requiring std concepts

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts, c++-modules

**IDE** : MSVS 2022, `/std:c++latest`, `/experimental:module`, x86 ;

**Goal** : to export `T add(T,T)` that `requires std::integral<T>` ;

This compiles (`test.ixx`) :

```
export module test;

template < typename T >
concept addable = requires ( T t1, T t2 ) {
    t1 + t2 ;
};

export template < typename T >
requires addable<T>
T add ( T t1, T t2 ) { return t1 + t2; }
```

This does not (`test.ixx`) :

```
export module test;

#include <concepts>

export template < typename T >
requires std::integral<T>
T add ( T t1, T t2 ) { return t1 + t2; }
```

The above code causes 2 errors `LNK2019`, details below ;

Tried to

1. `#include <concepts>` in a separate implementation file - failed ;
2. `import std.core;`, which seems to not yet be supported - failed ;

Usage sample (`main.cpp`) :

```
import test;
#include <iostream>

int main ()
{
    using namespace std;
   
    int    i = add(22,20);              // = 42
    double d = add(0.5,0.77);           // = 1.27

    cout << i << ", " << d << endl ;    // "42, 1.27"

    return 0;
}
```

Any ideas ?

Linker error details :

```
LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol __imp__ldiv::<!test> referenced in function "struct test::_ldiv_t __cdecl div(long,long)" (?div@@YA?AU_ldiv_t@test@@JJ@Z::<!test>)
```

```
LNK2019 : unresolved external symbol __imp__lldiv::<!test> referenced in function "struct test::_lldiv_t __cdecl div(__int64,__int64)" (?div@@YA?AU_lldiv_t@test@@_J0@Z::<!test>)
```

Comment: "*import std.core;, which seems to not yet be supported*" That's not part of C++20.

Comment: @NicolBolas It won't even be a part of C++23 - there will be [`std` and `std.compat`](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2465r1.pdf)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is, you shouldn't use `#include` after the module declaration `export module xxx`.

The introduction of modules does not change what `#include` means (well, in most cases), `#include` still means "copy-paste this file here". Your `#include`-ing of `<concepts>` pasted all its content and its transitive includes into your module, and your module now "owns" these definitions (they have *module linkage*). The compiler mangles names belong to modules differently, and that's what causes the linker errors.

You should instead use the *global module fragment* for `#include`-ing things:

```cpp
module;
#include <concepts>
export module test;
// contents
```

Or use "header units" (provided your compiler supports them) instead:

```cpp
export module test;
import <concepts>;
// contents
```

Comment: _global module fragment_ worked, while "header units" did not. It seems MSVS 2022 does not support "header units" at this moment. Thank you, @Chlorie!

Comment: Clarification: when using "header units", the MSVS compiler throws '`C7612` could not find header unit for `...\include\concepts`', so the support for "header units" seems to be there, but as @NicolBolas mentioned, there're problems importing them.

Comment: @PiotrTarasov: Note that compilers implement header units just fine (more or less). They have trouble with importing standard library headers as header units.